# Search for a Value in Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that was inherited that is not normalized in any way.  Here is the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Countries]
(
    [ISOCode] [NVARCHAR](5) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [EnglishName] [NVARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [DefaultWarehouse] [NVARCHAR](20) NULL,
    [IndividualOrderLimit] [MONEY] NULL,
    [ISOCode2] [NVARCHAR](5) NULL,
    [AltCode1] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode2] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode3] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode4] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode5] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode6] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode7] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode8] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode9] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [AltCode10] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Countries]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ISOCode] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see this table is scaled horizontal using the `AltCodeX` columns to hold alternative values. I need to write a query that will return the `ISOCode` and `Name` if the input value matches any of the column values.

I have this query but it seems to clunky. I did check the query execution plan and it is using the clustered index at 100%, I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way to write this query.

```
SELECT 
    [ISOCode], 
    [Name], 
    [EnglishName]
FROM
    Countries
WHERE
    [AltCode1] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode2] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode3] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode4] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode5] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode6] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode7] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode8] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode9] = '[Value]' OR 
    [AltCode10]= '[Value]'
```

We are using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: You shouldn't have 10 repeating columns `AltCode01` - `AltCode10` - this violates the **first normal form** of database design. If you have multiple values - do what you **should do** in a relational database - create a separate table and establish a **relationship**. That way, you can much more easily find the matching values, and you can have 1, 5, 10, or 333 values for any entry in `Countries` - that's the proper way to do it !

Comment: I understand the need to do a relational database.  This is a third party database that is why I said it was inherited and not normalized and why my query looks this way.

Comment: @john you can always create an import process to clean up the incoming data and structure it in normalized form, then use your better design to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using unpivot with a where clause?

```
SELECT ISOCode, Name, EnglishName, AltCode
FROM
    (SELECT ISOCode,Name, EnglishName, AltCode1, AltCode2, AltCode3, AltCode4, AltCode5, AltCode6, AltCode7, AltCode8, AltCode9, AltCode10
     FROM Countries) AS t1
UNPIVOT 
(AltCode FOR AltCodes IN (AltCode1, AltCode2, AltCode3, AltCode4, AltCode5, AltCode6, AltCode7, AltCode8, AltCode9, AltCode10) AS t2)
WHERE t2.AltCode='value';
```

Comment: That works.  There is a typo in the query missing a ")" by the AS t2.  Looking at the query execution plan though, this uses more nested loops and scans instead of 100% on the clustered index.  This is a good answer and I'll mark it so, but I think I'm stuck with the gross query I have.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the denormalized table is here to stay, you could "fold" your query with an `IN` operator:

```
WHERE '[Value]' IN ([AltCode1], [AltCode2], ..., [AltCode10])
```

This works for exact matches because equality is symmetric. If you were to use a non-symmetric operator, e.g. `LIKE`, you would need a different approach to reduce code duplication, such as making a table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfSearchCountries (
    @search_string VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT 
        [ISOCode], 
        [Name], 
        [EnglishName]
    FROM
        Countries
    WHERE
        [AltCode1]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode2]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode3]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode4]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode5]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode6]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode7]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode8]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode9]  LIKE @search_string OR 
        [AltCode10] LIKE @search_string
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivot using `apply`.  Then it is easy to use `like` or `=`:

```
select c.ISOCode, c.Name, c.EnglishName
from countries c cross apply
     (values (altcode1), (altcode2), . . .
     ) v(altcode)
where v.altcode = @value;
```

You can easily extend this to show *which* code matches:

```
select c.ISOCode, c.Name, c.EnglishName, v.which
from countries c cross apply
     (values (1, altcode1), (2, altcode2), . . .
     ) v(which, altcode)
where v.altcode = @value;
```